# found someone lurking in my LAN, not sure what to do next

Tags: networking, firewall, lan, ip, network-monitoring

I have DD WRT router with internal numbers all falling within 192.168.1.0/24.  I was looking on my firewall records this morning and found someone at 10.10.109.100 got blocked from accessing port 5353 UDP.  Also there seems to be a lot of multicast to 224.0.0.251 using this same 5353 port.  The computer it was accessing is my daughters little Ubuntu box running Linux Mint.  Now I'm seeing a ton of activity with the 192.168.1.255 address of my lan (not sure what that means) accessing ports 137 and 138 netbios of my daughters Ubuntu.

But I'm mostly concerned about the 10.10.109.100 as I know that is a privately assigned address.  A few weeks ago I saw something similar but it was at 192.168.160.4 which I don't have anything assigned to at all.

I did a nmap scan for 10.10.109.0/24 and found nothing.

WHat can I do to figure out what the deal is?  See attached screenshot from my firewall.
[image: firewall screenshot]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483717/what-is-the-multicast-doing-on-224-0-0-251

Comment: It might be normal.  Although I'm not sure about the 10.10 stuff.  That may be from a Backdoor.XLog trojan.  Anyway, it's blocked by your firewall.